# Does a .NET CQL Parser Exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, cql

I haven't been able to find a .NET (c#) [CQL](http://www.loc.gov/standards/sru/specs/cql.html) parser, despite my best Googling efforts. Anyone have one they'd be willing to share, or know if one exists? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If found [this](http://ncql.codeplex.com/) project (NCql) written in c#.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Too bad there really isn't any documentation other than "use the client app tool to run tests and figure everything out for yourself" lol.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own parser should be easy enough, at least looking at the syntax. But the parser isn't the hard part -- the real work begins in translating query expressions to equivalent syntax in other data sources.

If I were tasked with finding a solution here, an approach I would explore:

1. Write the CQL parser
2. Create a translation layer to incorporate LINQ
3. Add-in LINQ libraries (LINQ for SQL, LINQ for Objects, LINQ for yada-yada-yada)

As always, your mileage may vary.